# Time Deference between UTC and Local time

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I am trying to find out the Call duration between the Last call end time with current time.
I am getting Last update time from MySQl bin as **"2020-03-03T05:04:40.000Z"** and now i want to find duration with current time from React application but now i am trying this one in JS Fiddle . When i tried the below script always getting 10 to 15 minutes more the actual result. Could any one help me out to find the exact solution please.

```
<script>
var startTime, endTime,timeDiff;

startTime = new Date("2020-03-03T05:04:40.000Z");
endTime = new Date();
timeDiff = (endTime - startTime)/1000 ; //in ms
let seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
document.write(sec2time(seconds))


function sec2time(timeInSeconds) {
    var pad = function(num, size) { return ('000' + num).slice(size * -1); },
    time = parseFloat(timeInSeconds).toFixed(3),
    hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60),
    minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60,
    seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60),
    milliseconds = time.slice(-3);
    return pad(hours, 2) + ':' + pad(minutes, 2) + ':' + pad(seconds, 2);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) will do:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60
```

this returns the number of hours behind or ahead of UTC. (positive meaning behind).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, Actually the problem is with the Server time not the logic... I found that issue solved...